# How to change `clang-format` options to prevent braking braces

Tags: c, clang, clang-format

I have a C file named `asdf.c` (you can reproduce the problem with this, even if it does not compile):

```
struct turn_parameters turns[][NUM_MODES] =
    {
    [MOVE_LEFT] =
        {
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, -3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, -3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, -3. * PI},
        },
    [MOVE_RIGHT] =
        {
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, 3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, 3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, 3. * PI},
        },
    [MOVE_LEFT_90] =
        {
        {-0.05, .8, 219, 291, -2.3 * PI},
        {-0.05, .8, 219, 291, -2.3 * PI},
        {-0.05, .8, 219, 291, -2.3 * PI},
        },
    [MOVE_RIGHT_90] =
        {
        {-0.05, .8, 219, 291, 2.3 * PI},
        {-0.05, .8, 219, 291, 2.3 * PI},
        {-0.05, .8, 219, 291, 2.3 * PI},
        },
    [MOVE_LEFT_180] =
        {
        {-0.04, .7, 400, 479, -2.5 * PI},
        {-0.04, .7, 400, 479, -2.5 * PI},
        {-0.04, .7, 400, 479, -2.5 * PI},
        },
    [MOVE_RIGHT_180] =
        {
        {-0.04, .7, 400, 479, 2.5 * PI},
        {-0.04, .7, 400, 479, 2.5 * PI},
        {-0.04, .7, 400, 479, 2.5 * PI},
        },
};
```

Now, if I run `clang-format -i asdf.c` (using version 6.0.1, but I can reproduce it with version 5 too), I let `clang-format` do the formatting for me.

However, I would like my code to comply with some [Linux style guides](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html) (after all, I am programming in C, not C++), so I am using [`checkpatch.pl`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/scripts/checkpatch.pl) at the same time to check my code style. Checkpatch, however, is complaining about how `clang-format` formatted the code:

```
src/asdf.c:2: ERROR: that open brace { should be on the previous line
src/asdf.c:4: WARNING: Statements should start on a tabstop
src/asdf.c:4: ERROR: that open brace { should be on the previous line
src/asdf.c:10: WARNING: Statements should start on a tabstop
src/asdf.c:10: ERROR: that open brace { should be on the previous line
src/asdf.c:16: WARNING: Statements should start on a tabstop
src/asdf.c:16: ERROR: that open brace { should be on the previous line
src/asdf.c:22: WARNING: Statements should start on a tabstop
src/asdf.c:22: ERROR: that open brace { should be on the previous line
src/asdf.c:28: WARNING: Statements should start on a tabstop
src/asdf.c:28: ERROR: that open brace { should be on the previous line
src/asdf.c:34: WARNING: Statements should start on a tabstop
src/asdf.c:34: ERROR: that open brace { should be on the previous line
```

My question is, how can I configure `clang-format` to avoid those errors/warnings?

My current `.clang-format` configuration is as follows:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 8
UseTab: Always
BreakBeforeBraces: Linux
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
```

Comment: Did you review [this example](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#examples) or read the [Linux clang-format guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/process/clang-format.html).

Comment: @Myst Yeah, as you can see, my current `.clang-format` configuration matches the one provided in the example (plus some rules to prevent short functions/loop on a single line). Also, even if I use the `.clang-format` configuration file from the Linux kernel, the resulting style conflicts with the `checkpatch.pl` expected format (i.e.: open braces { should be on the previous line).

Comment: According to the guide, Sometimes "\[`clang-format`] is not perfect nor covers every single case, but it is good enough to be helpful"... consider adding `// clang-format off` before the troublesome section and formatting that part by hand (than use `// clang-format on` to reactivate).

Comment: @Myst Maybe not the answer I was looking for, but that actually works as a workaround. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you add `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All` to your `.clang-format` file, clang-format will not wrap the opening braces in your code if they are already on the previous lines. For example, the following code will not be ill-formatted by clang-format:

```
struct turn_parameters turns[][NUM_MODES] = {
    [MOVE_LEFT] = {
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, -3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, -3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, -3. * PI},
    },
    [MOVE_RIGHT] = {
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, 3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, 3. * PI},
        {0.02, .448, 166, 260, 3. * PI},
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually solved the issue with the provided source code example. Sadly, this had some unintended side effects on the rest of the source code (many changes required). I wish there was an option to apply those breaks only for the braces "{", but left all the binary operators' style as they were before.